# Usage of `+` within format specifiers in c

Tags: c, printf

Why is the output of the following program is `d`?

And also, please explain the use of `+` in the printf statement.

```
‪#‎include‬"stdio.h"
int main(){
    int a=1;
    printf("%d"+a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That `printf` is the same as `printf("d");` because adding `a`(1) to `"%d"` would result in `"d"`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that a string literal like `"%d"` is actually an array (which in this case converts to a pointer).

When you do `"%d"+a`, you're not appending `a` to the string literal, you're taking the pointer that points to this string, adding `a` to it, and printing the result.

Since `a` is 1, you're going to print starting one character after the start of `"%d"`, which would be `"d"`

Your code is equivalent to the following :

```
#‎include‬"stdio.h"
int main(){
    const char* str = "%d";
    printf(str+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The output is

```
d
```

because you add `a` to the pointer of a format. The format looks `"d"` now. The `a` is not perceived as the `printf` parameter.

Answer (score -2):

[printf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) takes the format string as the first parameter, then with the variables to replace the formatted variables with. You're attempting to use the `+` for string concatenation such as in Java. What you most likely meant to do is:

```
#‎include‬"stdio.h"
int main(){
    int a=1;
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The does not answer the question at all.